# Html and CSS link is not working in server

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

my css and html link is not working in server

I use node.js and express to work my server

my server.js is

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('veiw engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


const port = 8001 // 서버가 열릴 포트를 설정합니다.
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log('접속한 클라이언트 아이피는 ' + request.connection.remoteAddress)
  
  const content = fs.readFileSync('public/main.html')
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }) // 헤더 정보를 적습니다.
  response.write(content) // 제공할 내용을 적습니다.
  response.end() // 응답을 완료합니다.
})
// 서버를 실제로 실행합니다.
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('서버가 실행되었습니다!')
})
```

and my main.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="main.css">
    
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <p>FISMA</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="main.html">홈</a></li>
                <li><a href="./지도지도2.0/지도지도.html">과학 돋보기</a></li>
                <li><a href="./분야탐색/분야탐색.html">분야 탐색</a></li>
                <li><a href="./오늘의논문/오늘의논문.html">오늘의 논문</a></li>
                <li><a href="./내보관함/내보관함.html">내 보관함</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <section>

        </section>
        <footer>
            made by FISMA, Hanyang University, Department of Physics
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried adding
`app.use(express.static('public'));`
and others in server.js, but it's not working.

it's working pretty good when I just execute html, but it's not working when I upload in server and execute

Comment: Why there are 2 `app.use(express.static('public'));` in your code? Removing one of them may fix the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing that main.css is in the "public" directory with main.html Is your link to main.html working? `<a href="main.html">홈</a>`

Comment: I delete one of `app.use(express.static('public'));`, but it's not working.
And the link `<a href="main.html">홈</a>` is working